# Debug Breakpoint On z-Index Change of a Dynamically Created Element

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, z-index, yui

I am using a JS library that creates dialogs, but it's core code is very big and complex. The dialogs created have a CSS attribute `z-index: 2`, whereas I want them to use a larger number. The issue is that this CSS is set directly on the dialog's DIV wrapper during the JS library's runtime (so I can't overwrite them with an external CSS file due to rule preceedence).

I was wondering if there is a way in Chrome Developer Tools or in Firebug to setup a breakpoint for whenever a given, dynamically created element's `z-index` property is changed, given that I know what `id=""` and `class=""` it will be assigned? Basically, the breakpoint should be right before that z-index is set, so I can know where the number 2 comes from in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Firebug HTML tab, right-click on an element and select "Break on attribute change"

Comment: Yeah, but as I said the element is added dynamically to the DOM. When it's available for right clicking (so I can add a break point), it has already been rendered and its z-index has been already set. I would like to set a break point before that.

Comment: It sounds like you're using YUI?  I think the zIndex of 2 is just the default value.  You can configure the zIndex as a property: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/WidgetStack.html#attr_zIndex